# json response from mongo to array of values

Tags: python, mongodb, charts

i am trying to create a python chart from mongo aggregate response, my python code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, Markup, render_template, jsonify, request, json, url_for, Response
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from bson import json_util


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGONDB_NAME'] = 'xxxxxxx'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.qapf6.gcp.mongodb.net/xxxxxx'
mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/chart', methods=['POST', 'GET'] )
def chart():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        eps = mongo.db.sgsss.aggregate([
        {
        '$match': {'estado': 'AC', 'regimen': 'subsidiado'}
        },
        {
        '$group': { '_id': '$codigo_EPS', 'Afiliados': {'$sum': 1}}
        },
        {
        '$sort': {'Afiliados': -1}
        },
        { '$limit' : 5 }
        ])
        response = json_util.dumps(eps)
        print(response)
        return response
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The json results appears like this:

```
[{"_id": "ESS207", "Afiliados": 139377}, {"_id": "EPSS41", "Afiliados": 48616}, {"_id": "ESS024", "Afiliados": 35763}, {"_id": "CCF055", "Afiliados": 30391}, {"_id": "ESS133", "Afiliados": 24475}]
```

So i want to convert this response in an array like this:

```
labels = [
    'ESS207', 'EPSS41', 'ESS024', 'CCF055', 'ESS133'
]

values = [
    139377, 48616, 35763, 30391, 24475
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: You did nothing to parse the json string into objects or to manipulate the objects to get the 2 lists you desire ... what is your problem? Things you do not code do not get done by your program - maybe flesh out where your problem is?#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using list comprehension.

```
response = [{"_id": "ESS207", "Afiliados": 139377}, {"_id": "EPSS41", "Afiliados": 48616}, {"_id": "ESS024", "Afiliados": 35763}, {"_id": "CCF055", "Afiliados": 30391}, {"_id": "ESS133", "Afiliados": 24475}]

labels, values = [x.get("_id") for x in response], [x.get("Afiliados") for x in response]

print(labels, values)
#['ESS207', 'EPSS41', 'ESS024', 'CCF055', 'ESS133'] [139377, 48616, 35763, 30391, 24475]
```

**EDIT**

Okay seems like your response object is not a list of dicts, but a string? Then try this one:

```
import json

response = """[{"_id": "ESS207", "Afiliados": 139377}, {"_id": "EPSS41", "Afiliados": 48616}, {"_id": "ESS024", "Afiliados": 35763}, {"_id": "CCF055", "Afiliados": 30391}, {"_id": "ESS133", "Afiliados": 24475}]"""

labels, values = [x.get("_id") for x in json.loads(response)], [x.get("Afiliados") for x in json.loads(response)]

print(labels, values)
#['ESS207', 'EPSS41', 'ESS024', 'CCF055', 'ESS133'] [139377, 48616, 35763, 30391, 24475]
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Of what type is your response object? If it is a list of dicts it should work.

Comment: no, TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.

Comment: OMG, you wanted a list so got one .... if you want a tuple just convert the variables like `tuple(labels)` or for a string `str(labels)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
import json
labels = []
values = []

for item in json.loads(response):
    labels.append(item['_id'])
    values.append(item['Afiliados'])
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: can you post your response object?

Comment: [{"_id": "ESS207", "Afiliados": 139377}, {"_id": "EPSS41", "Afiliados": 48616}, {"_id": "ESS024", "Afiliados": 35763}, {"_id": "CCF055", "Afiliados": 30391}, {"_id": "ESS133", "Afiliados": 24475}]

Comment: what is your updated code ? because on this response code is working fine. i think your response object on which you are using. the above snippet that i have added is not the same

Comment: I guess it is not a list of dicts. From his code he dumps the eps object, that why it could be a string if you ask me.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
response = [{"_id": "ESS207", "Afiliados": 139377}, {"_id": "EPSS41", "Afiliados": 48616}, {"_id": "ESS024", "Afiliados": 35763}, {"_id": "CCF055", "Afiliados": 30391}, {"_id": "ESS133", "Afiliados": 24475}]
    
# Convert generator into list because it will be iterated twice
response = list(response)
# Always use .get instead of [] to avoid exceptions when the key is not present
labels = [element.get("_id") for element in response]
values = [element.get("Afiliados") for element in response]
print(labels, values)
['ESS207', 'EPSS41', 'ESS024', 'CCF055', 'ESS133'] [139377, 48616, 35763, 30391, 24475]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: If you are getting that it's because you are doing response = json_util.dumps(eps). That function converts your json into a String